# Putting jersey-bean-validation on classpath breaks application

Tags: java, rest, jersey, bean-validation

I have a simple Jersey application with a resource "/a":

```
@Path("/a")
public class AResource {
    @GET
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public ABody getA() {
        ABody body = new ABody();
        body.setProperty("example");
        return body;
    }
}
```

The class ABody:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ABody {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String property;

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String publicKey) {
        this. property = publicKey;
    }
}
```

The main class:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String baseUri = "http://localhost:9998/";
    final ResourceConfig rc = ResourceConfig().packages("com.example");

    System.out.println("Starting grizzly...");
    HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(baseUri), rc);

    System.in.read();
    httpServer.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Everything works fine, when I request "/a" I get a JSON object with the property.
I tried to include the dependency jersey-bean-validation to have the object of type ABody automatically validated when it is requested.

The problem: The method "getA()" is not executed anymore as soon as the new dependency is included.

I want to use bean validation to validate the body of incoming and outgoing requests. I followed the official [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e11956) documentation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain "The method "getA()" is not executed anymore as soon as the new dependency is included."? Is it really not executed anymore? Did you check with some logging or did you debug it? Is there an exception instead? What is the return code/value?

Comment: I tried with log4j and debugging. There seems to be no exception, the server just replies to all requests with an empty response.

Comment: How are u adding validation? Are u using Application class?

Comment: No, I added the main class to the question.